# IBM Conversation API - What should be a endpoint URL and Parameters

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

I try to access IBM conversation using Postman tool but getting 404 (Resource not found) error.

EndPoint : https://gateway.watsonplatform.net/conversation/api/v1/workspaces/883c7704-02c4-41fc-b8a0-aea1d0325c5a/message?version=2016-09-20

my workspace id = 883c7704-02c4-41fc-b8a0-aea1d0325c5a

Is there anything wrong in endpoint or parameter?.
How to pass version?

Answer (score 0):

Your endpoint looks correct if you're trying to send a message to conversation: https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/conversation/api/v1/?curl#send_message

Try changing the version to the most updated: `version=2017-05-26`